# Why do I have to call the other app before using grantUriPermission?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

I'm little bit puzzled about [grantUriPermission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#grantUriPermission(java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri,%20int)) function. I'd like to use it to grant file access to another application via a [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). Since FileProvider must be local (non-exported) for good reason, I must grant the other app temporary read/write permission. Documentation says:

> Normally you should use Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
>   Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION with the Intent being used to
>   start an activity instead of this function directly. If you use this
>   function directly, you should be sure to call revokeUriPermission(Uri,
>   int) when the target should no longer be allowed to access it.

Fair enough, since I don't need to open an activity nor explicitly start a service (the other app would just ask for that file when its time comes), I though I'm fine with just plain:

```
Uri newFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, file);
grantUriPermission(OTHER_APP_PACKAGE_NAME, newFileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

To my surprise, I was still getting the security exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{42ee0b98 5878:example.com.myapplication3/u0a82} (pid=5878, uid=10082) that is not exported from uid 10081
```

After few experiments I found out that I **must** call the other app via an Intent at least once:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(OTHER_APP_PACKAGE_NAME, OTHER_APP_SERVICE_NAME);
startService(intent);
```

As soon as I do this, I can do everything as expected -- I can remove this intent code, I can even reinstall both apps and it still works (!). It seems like there's a hidden requirement that the owner must call the other app at least once and its stored somewhere in the system.

Is this documented somewhere?

**EDITED:** first I thought I have to use Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION flag, too but this seems to be not necessary.